# Actualizar multiples registros con Laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent, querybuilder

Antes que nada gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer mi pregunta.
Bueno mi problema es el siguiente quiero actualizar multiples registros en mi base de datos a partir de una consulta la cual me obtiene los registros que quiero actualizar, el campo que quiero actualizar es "is_active" el cual quiero poner en false en todos mis registros ya obtenidos comparto mi constula la cual obtiene los datos:

```
$tabulatorsHistory = DB::table('cat_tabulator_histories')->where('id_tabulator', $name)->get();
```

El $name lo obtengo de otra consulta para poder traer los datos que me interesan.

He leido que un foreach resolveria el problema pero que esta forma de resolver consume muchos recursos en la base de datos.
Estoy intentando cambiar mis datos de esta manera graicas a un ejemplo que encontre en google pero no logro implementarlo.

```
$tabulatorsHistory = DB::update(DB::raw(“UPDATE cat_tabulator_histories SET is_active = false WHERE id_tabualator = $name AND is_active = true”));
```

Este es el ejemplo original que encontre en linea:

```
$notices = DB::update(DB::raw(“UPDATE notices SET is_read = 1 WHERE user_id = 1 AND is_read =0”));
```

De ante mano agradezco cualquier opinión o consejo que puedan brindarme, si necesitan más datos con gusto la comparto, gracias.

Comment: No sé si entiendo. ¿Cuál es la condición para que un registro deba ser modificado? ¿Quieres modificar todos los registros que en la columna `id_tabualator` tengan el valor que está en la variable `$name`?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario, es correcto quiero actualizar todos los registros de la tabla cat_tabulator_histories cuyo id_tabulator coincidan con la variable $name, (id_tabulator) es un string en mi base de datos, lo que quiero lograr es cambiar el campo is_active de todos esos registros a false. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Ok. En la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-statements) hay un ejemplo muy parecido a lo que quieres hacer, sólo tendrías que cambiar el nombre de la tabla y las columnas, y el valor que quieres setear (`0` en tu caso). Prueba eso y comenta si tienes algún inconveniente

Comment: Lo intente bro no me funciono, igual agraadezco tu ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para evitar el uso de foreach y modifica múltiples registro puede utiliza la siguiente función

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-updates
si leer la documentación el uso del siguiente código solo se utliza en caso especiales

```
use App\catTabulatorHistoriesModel;


catTabulatorHistoriesModel::where('id_tabualator',1)
->where('is_active',true)->update(['is_active'=>false,]);
```

introducir el código aquí

```
$notices = DB::update(DB::raw(“UPDATE notices SET is_read = 1 WHERE user_id = 1 AND is_read =0”));
```

se toma la consulta anterio y la convertimos en El ORM de Eloquent incluido con Laravel

```
NoticesModel::where('user_id',1)->where('is_read',0)->update(['is_read'=>1]);
```

ademas tiene que crear el modelo catTabulatorHistoriesModel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class catTabulatorHistoriesModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'cat_tabulator_histories';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

se puede hacer de diferentes maneras:

```
 $tabulatorsHistory = DB::table('cat_tabulator_histories')
          ->where('id_tabulator', $name)
          ->where('is_active', true)
          ->update(['is_active' => false]);
```

tambien asi

```
$cats = CatTabHistory::where('id_tabualator', $name)
      ->where('is_active', true)
      ->update(['is_active' => false]);
```

donde `CatTabHistory` es el modelo relacionado con tu tabla.

Comment: Hola sergio tu implementación funciona a la perfección igual la probe y funciona muchas gracias.